# AngularJS app have different behavior locally and on Heroku

Tags: node.js, angularjs, heroku, express

I have written an app using the MEAN-stack(MongoDB, Express, AngularJS Node.js). Locally everything works as its supposed to but for some reason it behaves differently when I run it on [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/).

The problem is that some of my angular controllers are transferred with the content type header text/html instead of application/javascript. As stated this is not a problem locally.

I have updated my npm and bower packages so everything should be up to date. Except for express where I use v. 3.4.4(because version 4.x.x requires a rewrite of the config). I use the same version of the frame works locally and on heroku.

Please let me know if I can provide any more information that would make it easier to solve the problem.

Regards

Comment: The URL of the app on Heroku might help...

Comment: Another difference in the environment is the load balancing in Heroku. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing though express should be consistent with the content types. It defaults to text/html when you set a string as the response.

Comment: When you say different behavior, what is exactly ? Not working at all ? Or simply some part of your code that is not working ?

Comment: @Aperçu : " A couple of my Controller is transferred as type text/html instead of application/javascript as most of the controllers are transferred as(the same files are transferred as app/js when I run it locally)." I suspect this breaks my code.

Comment: Make sure you are constructing your controllers to allow for minification. https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05

Comment: @csbarnes: Thank you for your suggestion but it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Process of elimination:- Try plain http-server....npm install -g http-server   Then run http-server at your doc root. If things work fine Express needs to be configured correctly.

Comment: Could you provide us some code that you suspect to be problematic?

Comment: Can you check to see that version of all libs (npm, bower) are the same on heroku and on your machine. Try runing `heroku run npm list` if you have heroku toolbelt. And `npm list` locally. Also provide the output of the `heroku run env` and `env` commands. MAKE SURE TO REMOVE PASSWORDS THOUGH!

Answer (score 2):

In most of the cases, when your scripts are transferred as `text/html`, it's because they are not found and return an `HTML 404` page, you can check it using the `Chrome Developer Tools` in the `Network tab`.

When you have this issue, there is a lot of chance that your app is completely broken and that's why I ask you this.

Don't know if you're using some tasks runner like `Grunt` for your deployment process or just pushing your project as is but in both cases you need to check that the path of your files are correctly set by checking the requested `url` of yours scripts transferred with the wrong `MIME TYPE`.

Had also same problem with the `Yeoman` generator that was messing with the `minification` and file renaming some time ago.

Comment: I have checked my Heroku log and all the files are found.

Comment: Could you please look at the content of these files ? Is it the right content with the wrong `MIME TYPE` ?

Comment: The content is wrong. It's HTML and not JavaScript.

Comment: Is the requested resource path corresponding to the effective file location in your deployed app ?

Comment: I'm referreing to theese files the same way I do with the others that are working and they are all at the same location.

Comment: Check the permissions on those files. They might not load because they just aren't public enough.

Comment: The permissions should be fine